# Hibernate automatically performs a DELETE query on ManyToMany relation when executing a SELECT

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem with a self ManytoMany relation. When I check if a relation between two tags exists, Hibernate cleans the relation performing a DELETE.

I've tried to change LAZY to EAGER and to add or remove a "relatedTagsOf" with inverted column names but this didn't solve my problem. I also tried to change the Select using a fetch join.

This is the entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String code;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "tag_related_tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "relatedTagId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tagId")
    )
    private Set<Tag> relatedTags = new HashSet<>();


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

And this is the query:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 
                FROM tag_related_tags trt 
                WHERE (trt.tag_id = :masterTagId AND trt.related_tag_id = :relatedTagId) 
                   OR (trt.related_tag_id = :relatedTagId AND trt.tag_id = :masterTagId)"
      , nativeQuery = true)

Integer existRelation(@Param("masterTagId") Long masterTagId, 
                      @Param("relatedTagId") Long relatedTagId);
```

If I have 2 rows into "tag_related_tags" table like this:

```
+------------------------+
|related_tag_id | tag_id |
+------------------------+
|1458           | 1459   |
|1459           | 1458   |
+------------------------+
```

..and execute the select using `1459` and a new `1460` as parameters, hibernate remove the rows.

What I need is to execute the SELECT statement without deleting these rows.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the sql statements that are executed?

Comment: Select doesn't persist any data. Debug the query being generated from. Hibernate and please confirm the queries being run.

Comment: Hibernate:delete from tag_related_tags where related_tag_id=?
DEBUG o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister - Done deleting collection
Deleting collection: [..entity.Tag.relatedTagsOf#1458]
15:43:09 [http-nio-4000-exec-7] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL-delete from tag_related_tags where tag_id=?
Hibernate: delete from tag_related_tags where tag_id=?
15:43:09[http-nio-4000-exec-7] DEBUG o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister - Done deleting collection
Hibernate: SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM tag_related_tags trt WHERE (trt.tag_id = ? AND trt.related_tag_id = ?) OR (trt.related_tag_id = ? AND trt.tag_id = ?)